# Sendkeys NOT working for textfield

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, exception

While trying the below code

```
driver.findElement(By.id("txt_UserName")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txt_UserName'][@name='txt_UserName'][@class='formInput']")).sendKeys(new String("karthik"));
driver.findElement(By.name("txt_Password")).clear();
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string
```

Comment: Can you share HTML dom structure?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you have mismatched your coding standards.

```
WebElement userName= driver.findElement(By.id("txt_UserName"));
userName.clear();
userName.sendKeys("karthik");

WebElement paswd= driver.findElement(By.id("txt_Password"));
paswd.clear();
paswd.sendKeys("Enter your Password");

paswd.submit();
```

Confirm once your locators of Username & Password field and use it in above code....